# Using two same named angular directives from different modules in a project

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive, angular-leaflet-directive, angular-chart

I am using `angular-leaflet-directive` for rendering map and `angular-chart` for rendering charts in a project. Both are very handy libraries unless you want to enable legend for your charts.

In this case, to enable legend for `angular-chart` directive, you definitely need to set `legend` attribute to `true`. Once it is done if `angular-leaflet-directive` is also enabled for the module, error occurs since leaflet module tries to compile its own directive, then complains about missing `leaflet` controller.

It is a pity that `angular-leaflet-directive` has not prefixed its directives, as it is explained in angular docs. But it is not the main concern.

Is there any method to prevent a directive to be compiled for similar scenarios, what should a developer do, if its two different modules has picked same name for their directives?

Comment: Thank you @NewDev it has solved my problem. I think you should try to write down solution as answer, so that I can accept it as answer.

Comment: It's not my answer, so I will just flag this question as a duplicate and encourage others to do the same and upvote the answer